# How to submit a multipart image - Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, multer, form-data

I have a client side javascript sdk that submits an image to a server side node.js api that uses the multer library to parse the image.

However ive noticed if i set a header to be `content-type` `multipart-formdata` multer will throw an error saying

> Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

```
async submitDocument(id, side, image) {

        const url = this.API_URL + "/api/document";

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.set("image", image, "front.jpg");
        formData.set("side", side);

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.API_KEY);

        const request = {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            headers: headers,
        };

        try {

            const response = await fetch(url, request);
            const data = await response.json();

            return data;

        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the error message says, a `multipart/form-data` content-type requires a `boundary` parameter.

Don't set the `Content-Type` yourself. Allow the browser to generate it from the `formData` object.

Answer (score -1):

`npm` module `connect-multiparty` may helpful to you. From server-side node application.

`server.js`

```
const multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
const multipartMiddleware = multipart();  
router.post('/api/document', multipartMiddleware);
router.post('/api/document', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files)
})
```

post-man api test sample -
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxBpz.png

Comment: Nothing suggests that the OP is using *connect*, the module's documentation says "I actually recommend against using this module.", and this doesn't seem to solve the problem of the request being malformed.